# Make new 2D array in third dimension for every element in 1D array, pythonically

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Say you have two 1D arrays with the same size
`a=[1,8,4,5,9]`
`b=[1,8,4,5,9]`
and then for every ith element in a and b, can you make a new array such that,
[image]

where H is a matrix of matrices and H(i) is stacked in a third dimension?

I have tried using numpys np.dstack however it seems like it treats every new element inputted separately. 
Doing this with a for loop would be trivial, however I believe that they are slow in python and thus wish to do this in a pythonic way, with numpy if possible.

so then for `H[0]` we would have `[[1,16,16],[1,7,1],[1,4,2]]`
and similarly for `H[1]` we would have `[[64,16,16],[64,56,64],[8,32,16]]`

Comment: can you post the real expected result, not image?

Comment: Added expected result. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you're looking for a solution that can use numpy, or do you want no imports?

Comment: Yes numpy is welcome, shall edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `column_stack` to stack the calculated results and then `reshape`:

```
a=np.array([1,8,4,5,9])
b=np.array([1,8,4,5,9])
​
np.column_stack((
    a ** 2, 2 * a, 2 * a,
    b * a,  7 * a, b * a,
    b,      4 * b, 2 * b  
)).reshape(-1,3,3)

Out[468]:
array([[[ 1,  2,  2],
        [ 1,  7,  1],
        [ 1,  4,  2]],

       [[64, 16, 16],
        [64, 56, 64],
        [ 8, 32, 16]],

       [[16,  8,  8],
        [16, 28, 16],
        [ 4, 16,  8]],

       [[25, 10, 10],
        [25, 35, 25],
        [ 5, 20, 10]],

       [[81, 18, 18],
        [81, 63, 81],
        [ 9, 36, 18]]])
```

Comment: This is rather beautiful. And its pretty much a one liner, rather than having a for loop style iteration.